# Ensemble learning using neural network as combination technique

Tags: python

I wanna implement and ensemble learning model using the power of 3 base learners KNN; DT and RF then combine results of prediction using a weighted technique in the following example neural network with perceptron was an used as a combination techniques based on optimizing the weights till finding the best weight and therefore determining the performance of the model. i got this error while implementing the model :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-bd170b55dfe3> in <module>()
     35 p = Perceptron(random_state=42, max_iter=10)
     36 #fit the model
---> 37 p.fit(pred, y_test)
     38 for value in pred:
     39     pr = p.predict([value])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\stochastic_gradient.py in fit(self, X, y, coef_init, intercept_init, sample_weight)
    584                          loss=self.loss, learning_rate=self.learning_rate,
    585                          coef_init=coef_init, intercept_init=intercept_init,
--> 586                          sample_weight=sample_weight)
    587 
    588 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\stochastic_gradient.py in _fit(self, X, y, alpha, C, loss, learning_rate, coef_init, intercept_init, sample_weight)
    416             self.classes_ = None
    417 
--> 418         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, 'csr', dtype=np.float64, order="C")
    419         n_samples, n_features = X.shape
    420 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    571     X = check_array(X, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite,
    572                     ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples,
--> 573                     ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    574     if multi_output:
    575         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    449         if not allow_nd and array.ndim >= 3:
    450             raise ValueError("Found array with dim %d. %s expected <= 2."
--> 451                              % (array.ndim, estimator_name))
    452         if force_all_finite:
    453             _assert_all_finite(array)

ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

Here is the code of the ensemble model

```
 import pandas
    from sklearn import model_selection
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
    from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn import tree
    from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
    from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
    from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron
    iris = load_iris()
    np.random.seed(1)
    X=iris.data
    y=iris.target
    Y = (iris.target==0).astype(np.int8)

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =model_selection.train_test_split(
        X,Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=123)
    #Build ensemble model using neural netowork as combination
    model1 = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1)
    model2 = KNeighborsClassifier()
    model3 = RandomForestClassifier()
    model1.fit(X_train,y_train)
    model2.fit(X_train,y_train)
    model3.fit(X_train,y_train)
    pred1=model1.predict(X_test)
    pred2=model2.predict(X_test)
    pred3=model3.predict(X_test)
    #Combination of results and detmination of weights using neural network 
    #First  trial using simple perceptron 
    #input layer containing the three neurons representing the results of prediction 
    pred=[[pred1,pred2,pred3]]
    #output layer containg y_test 
    out=y_test 
    #creating a perceptron model
    p = Perceptron(random_state=42, max_iter=10)
    #fit the model
    p.fit(pred, y_test)
    for value in pred:
        pr = p.predict([value])
        print([pr])
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the correction i made mistakes on the splitting length but unfortunately  i got a terrible results i have to work on to improve it the model overfitted and need a lot of correction elow i share the code:

```
import pandas
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
import numpy as np
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron
iris = load_iris()
np.random.seed(1)
X=iris.data
y=iris.target
Y = (iris.target==0).astype(np.int8)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =model_selection.train_test_split(
    X,Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=123)
#Build ensemble model using neural netowork as combination
model1 = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1)
model2 = KNeighborsClassifier()
model3 = RandomForestClassifier()
model1.fit(X_train,y_train)
model2.fit(X_train,y_train)
model3.fit(X_train,y_train)
pred1=model1.predict(X_test)
pred2=model2.predict(X_test)
pred3=model3.predict(X_test)
#Combination of results and detmination of weights using neural network 
#First  trial using simple perceptron 
#input layer containing the three neurons representing the results of prediction 
pred=np.array([pred1,pred2,pred3]).T
#split dataset
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train1, X_test1, y_train1, y_test1 = train_test_split(pred, out)
#output layer containg y_test 
out=y_test 
#creating a perceptron model
perceptron = Perceptron(random_state=42, max_iter=10)
#fit the model
perceptron.fit(X_train1,y_train1)
predictions = perceptron.predict(X_test1)
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix
print(confusion_matrix(y_test1,predictions))
print(classification_report(y_test1,predictions))
```